# animated button for my iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i am developing app for my iphone most of her was completed.
now i want to add another button but i want it to be spaciel button. 
the shap of the button will be like radar screen and when i press it i want from the button to spin around.

can someone help me with guidlines.

thanks

Comment: UIButton is a UIView - have you tried applying any of the animation methods in the UIView documentation to a button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

CABasicAnimation *spinbuttonAnime;
spinbuttonAnime = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
spinbuttonAnime.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
spinbuttonAnime.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:((360*M_PI)/180)];
spinbuttonAnime.duration = 0.5;
spinbuttonAnime.repeatCount = 1;
[myButton addAnimation:spinbuttonAnime forKey:@"180"];

Comment: thanks for the help,does there is more property for transform. ??

Answer (score 0):

Use transform property of you UIButton to translate, rotate or scale its ;-) 
As Adam Ebernach said, a UIButton is a UIView so you can do all same animation with UIView and UIButton :-)